# jQuery Attr() Function Stop Bubbling

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Is there a way to stop the attr() function in jQuery from bubbling up the DOM tree (or down)? I tried the stopPropagation() function, but it doesn't seem to work for attr(). In my code, I have a function that is called on attr(), and in that function I have 2 other attr() methods I also call functions in. I essentially have the jQuery version of a nested foreach loop (but I tried each() but it didn't work). Is there another way to stop bubbling?

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#assessform_page").on("submit", "#assessform", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        assessrows = {};
        url = $(this).attr("action");

        $("div").attr("data-test-num", function(k) {
                    k.stopPropagation();
            assessrows[k + 1] = {};
            $("input, select").attr("data-tab-row", function(v) {
                            v.stopPropagation();
                assessrows[k + 1][$(this).attr("data-tab-row")] = $(this).val();
            });
            $("label").attr("data-tab-row", function(v) {
                            v.stopPropagation();
                assessrows[k + 1][$(this).attr("data-tab-row")] = $(this).text();
            });
        });
        console.log(assessrows);

    });

});
```

My HTML code:

```
<form id="assessform" action="review.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="assessform">
    <div data-test-num="1">
        <label data-tab-row="objname">First Value: </label>
        <select autofocus="autofocus" data-tab-row="status">
            // options
        </select>
        <input type="text" data-tab-row="numer" value="" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div data-test-num="2">
        <label data-tab-row="objname">Second Value: </label>
        <select data-tab-row="status">
            // options
        </select>
        <select data-tab-row="numer">
            // options
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" data-tab-row="denom" value="1" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `attr()` reads/changes atttributes. There's nothing in there that bubbles.

Comment: Side note, you can also just use `.data('test-num')` to get & `.data('test-num', 'new value')` to set these. It's also faster.

Comment: I think in the function it propagates.

Comment: It can't propagate. that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Something propagates. In the `console.log`, the array that is created, "assessrow", keeps being overwritten by values that would not be there if it didn't propagate.